# How to encrypt value use capicom in java

Tags: java, encryption, dll, capicom

I have implemented encryption capicom using python. how to set algorithm key length, name and secret with java?

```
def encrypt(key,content):
    EncryptedData = win32com.client.Dispatch('CAPICOM.EncryptedData')
    EncryptedData.Algorithm.KeyLength = 0
    EncryptedData.Algorithm.Name = 4
    EncryptedData.SetSecret(key)
    EncryptedData.Content = content
    return EncryptedData.Encrypt()
```

Comment: take a look at apache-codec might help.

Comment: I've reverted your edit to your question, because having an answer in the question will confuse future readers. Instead, you can post your own answer, but please add more than just a link to a pull-request. You should describe how you solved it and show how it can be used.